# QBCOCustomObject fields property returning nil for key

Tags: ios, parsing, quickblox

I am surprised by this behaviour or i do not know confidently that its might be my mistake.The problem is when i am retrieving records from Quickblox API which are `QBCOCustomObject` instances.I am getting the instance properties in debugger console but when accessing those values using keys i am getting nil and crashing as with the Swift force wrapping feature.

This is my console output for QuickBlox API.

```
         {
    "class_name" = PLProjectMember;
    items =     (
                {
            "_id" = 57177bd263f2d26030d616a0;
            "_parent_id" = 57177bd2a0eb47c43b000019;
            "created_at" = 1461156818;
            name = "Ajay Babu";
            "updated_at" = 1461156818;
            "user_id" = 11736197;
        },
                {
            "_id" = 57177bd263f2d26030d616a1;
            "_parent_id" = 57177bd2a0eb47c43b000019;
            "created_at" = 1461156818;
            name = "Ajay Nath";
            "updated_at" = 1461156818;
            "user_id" = 11736197;
        }
    );
    limit = 0;
    skip = 0;
}
```

I am accessing values like this,once i get the QBCOCustomObject instance.For example say my instance is `firstCustomObject` after parsing the result.Here is the code for getting vales,

```
 firstCustomObject.fields?.valueForKey("name") // Worked Great
 firstCustomObject.fields?.valueForKey("_id")//Crash as its giving nil
 firstCustomObject.fields?.valueForKey("_parent_id")//Crash
 firstCustomObject.fields?.valueForKey("updated_at")//Crash
```

I have also used `objectForKey()` method also, but the same is happening Crash. Other than name key all are giving me back `nil` and leading app to crash. Can any one come across this problem, please give me suggestion for getting resolved.

Answer (score 0):

i never though that i would get the answer and give it back this much early.The solution is here,

https://sdk.quickblox.com/ios/documentation/Classes/QBCOCustomObject.html#//api/name/customObject

QBCOCustomObject having properties ID,parentID,userID.we can directly access the values from thee instance.Like,

```
    firstCustomObject.ID
    firstCustomObject.userID
    firstCustomObject.parentID.
```